# Make Procedural Texture Rotate with Geometry Nodes Object?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, procedural

I've added a cube object in geometry nodes, and I've given it a Procedural noise texture as the material. When I rotate the cube using the transform node, the noise texture doesn't rotate with the cube object. **(See Images)** Is there a way to make it so that the noise texture stays mapped to the cube, no matter how the cube is rotated? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a few answers here that will help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251426/material-shifts-in-geo-nodes/251433#251433

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an attribute node into the material nodes, and plug the vector of the attribute into the vector of the noise texture.
Then in the name, write: `uv_map`

**Thanks to @Benus for showing me this post:**
[Material shifts in geo nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251426/material-shifts-in-geo-nodes/251433#251433)

[image]

Comment: Looking forward to the next procedural textures video then :D